# 'process.env.NODE_ENV' replaced as a string or process object is available at runtime in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Have seen code which does something of this sort,

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        //some DEVELOPMENT mode operation 
 }
```

and on similar lines, process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'.
Now when we do `npm run build`, on create-react-app scaffolded app, does,

1. process.env.NODE_ENV string is replaced (and becomes `if('development' === 'development')`, and which case dead code is removed?  ) or,
2. `process` object is available at runtime and when this code is executed it has this object with `env` object containing NODE_ENV property.

The process is important to know, because have seen people write down function like `getENV` which returns this value. If #1 happens this doesn't help to remove dead code.

Comment: did you test it?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process #1 is the one that happens. Everything works because of webpack `DefinePlugin`, which "translates" process.env to the correct value.

Now, the tricky thing here is: Webpack does the deadcode elimination (a.k.a Tree shaking) during the build time, which removes all the branches that are not needed.